# Setting up emacsclient (OSX)

Tags: emacsclient, server

I am trying to set up emacs to run as a server to avoid the time required to open individual sessions for each file. This is on OS X El Capitan. Using the instructions provided  [here](http://pragmaticemacs.com/emacs/using-server-and-clients-for-instantaneous-startup/), I have the first item described, the emacs executable I presume, at the indicated location on my system:

`/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --daemon`

However the second item described, the emacsclient, is not present (or visible) at the indicated location:

`/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9/emacsclient -c $argv`

Will I need to install emacsclient separately? I used homebrew to set up emacs originally on this system. Does this method not install emacsclient by default?

Comment: That command line for emacsclient looks like it's for the emacsformacosx.com builds. I think (although I'm not sure and am not at my Mac just now) that emacsclient should just be under bin, not bin-x86-blahblahblah, assuming your homebrew install built it from scratch. You can use cd and ls to look at what's inside Emacs.app like it's just a normal directory structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you used Homebrew to set up Emacs, then you should have emacsclient symlinked under /usr/local/bin/emacsclient.

Simply add `(server-start)` to your init file, and then emacsclient $FILE should open $FILE on your existing session.

I recommend installing Emacs using the following command:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-ctags --with-gnutls --with-librsvg --with-mailutils --with-imagemagick@6 --with-modules
```

Don't forget the `with-imagemagick@6`, since that is fundamental for proper handling of images, should you ever need it.
I don't think the brew cask installation ships with emacsclient. If that is what you did, try reinstalling it with the command above.

Comment: The above suggestion works. There is a symlink to emacsclient at the indicated location. Is there a difference between starting the server using the `server-start` and the `-daemon` mode? It seems the former exits the server when the frame exits but the latter keeps the service running in the background until `M-x kill-emacs` is invoked (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/emacsclient-Options.html#emacsclient-Options)). I prefer the latter. How do I invoke the daemon using the version installed by homebrew?